# Ember switch/index if, etc

Tags: ember.js

Ember seems to be quite lacking in the comparison department. You can only compare to zero using the #if helper and all the cool extended helpers people have written do not work with @index..., so you can't do something like

```
{{#each}}
    {{#xif '@index == 3'}}
        ....
    {{/xif}}
{{/each}}
```

which would provide specialization(for @index == 3).

Does anyone know how to essentially do the above? I have an loop but I need to specialize on certain indices.

ideally a switch statement would be nice(possible to hack handlebars to add this?)

e.g,

```
{{#each}}
    {{#switch @index}}
        {{case 0}}
            ....
        {{/case}}
        {{case 1}}
            ....
        {{/case}}
        {{default}}
            ....
        {{/default}}
    {{/switch}}
{{/each}}
```

etc...

Right now I'm having to use jquery to specialize the loop which makes for an inconsistent experience.

Comment: An inconsistent experience? What kind of one, for whom?

Answer (score 6):

Up front, I agree, a comparison if would be awesome, but the powers that be are against it since you're putting "too much logic in the template."

Index can be accessed using `_view.contentIndex`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mugokaka/1/edit

And switch is just syntactic sugar for an if statement, so it can still be accomplished, but again, it isn't a comparison, just truthy, and a little ugly.

```
{{#if statementOne}}
   foo 1
{{else}}
  {{#if statementTwo}}
     foo 2
  {{else}}
    //yadda
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

They generally recommend putting the logic in the controller, and having it return a truthy statement.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is to reduce complexity and when I have to specialize on one or two cases but write a lot of jquery code to do so then there is more "logic" in the code behind.. I was able to create a function to do what I want but could be extended to make it more powerful. Not sure how well it works in general though.

Answer (score 3):

You can now chain else blocks with `else if`.  Although see Kingpin2k's answer.

```
{{#if isAtWork}}
  Ship that code!
{{else if isReading}}
  You can finish War and Peace eventually...
{{/if}}
```

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_chained-else-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Ember/Handlebars limits the logic available in templates for a very clear philosophical reason, in line with its prescriptive approach to many things. It believes that templates should not be littered with computations and other business-like logic.

The urge to write a switch in a template--or in any language, for that matter--can already be considered a kind of "code smell". It often indicates that something in your code has not been factored/structured correctly. It could be that you need to break down your controllers and/or views into finer-grained subclasses, or simply that you'd be better off putting this switch/case logic into your controller or view, where it's easier to read and maintain. You didn't give any examples of why you want to use a switch/case; if you had, maybe someone could comment further on good ways to handle it.